# How to use StdLexical class in Scala

Tags: parsing, scala

I have been trying to use `scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical.StdLexical` but I'm not sure how to do it. I have been trying like this:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical.StdLexical

class Foo extends StdLexical {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val input = """
    class Main {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println("hello world")
      }
    }
    """
    val scanner = new Scanner(input)

    println(scanner.first)
  }
}
```

It compiles and runs but nothing is printed. Can anyone give me a simple example using this class? (Preferably I want to get all the tokens at once in a list or similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get any output because you use `class` instead of `object`, thus your code is never executed.

To get all token, you must fetch them manually:

```
def loop(s: Scanner, token: Seq[Token]): Seq[Token] =
  if (s.atEnd) token
  else loop(s.rest, token :+ s.first)

println(loop(new Scanner(input), Vector()))
```

Nevertheless, `StdLexical` doesn't tokenise the complete Scala grammar. If you need this, I suggest to use [Scalariform](https://github.com/mdr/scalariform) and its [tokenise](https://github.com/mdr/scalariform/blob/master/scalariform/src/main/scala/scalariform/lexer/ScalaLexer.scala#L260) method.

Comment: Ahh missed that one, still pretty new to Scala. It doesn't parse all the grammar as you say but I just wanted to see it in action, I've got other plans. Thanks a bunch..